# AWS: Forwarding HTTPS to HTTP via ELB

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm having issues setting up HTTPS on AWS via a load balancer. I've managed to get as far as proxying my standard :80 server, via HTTPS on the load balancer, so requests to https://www.example.com *are* working. So if AWS can handle HTTPS traffic at the ELB level, do I actually *need* to start a separate web server to handle the HTTPS traffic, or can I just leave it at that?

What are the disadvantages of proxying HTTPS -> HTTP using an AWS load balancer?

Answer (score 1):

Even without ELB, you don't need two web servers - Apache, nginx, IIS and other popular webservers can all serve HTTP and HTTPS at the same time.

That said, you can leave it the way you have it now, with one caveat - traffic between the ELB and your EC2 instance is unencrypted. As it's on Amazon's internal network, this is *reasonably* secure, but if you're transmitting stuff like credit cards and social security numbers, you'll want it encrypted all the way (especially if PCI compliance comes into play).

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should have said "VirtualHost". Traffic doesn't involve financial data, so I guess I'll be OK - it's not ideal, but good enough for the time-being. Thanks for the info.